# When does a Leprechaun's Ongoing ability activate?

Tags: smash-up

Consider the following scenario:

**Leprechaun (Tricksters Minion):**

> Ongoing: After another player plays a minion here with less power than this minion's power, destroy it (resolve its ability first).

**Commission (Bear Cavalry Action):**

> Play an extra minion. Then move another player's minion from the extra minion's base to another base.

**The Play**

1. A Leprechaun has a power of 5 and has been previously played on a base.
2. An opponent later plays Commission as their action, playing their extra minion on the same base as the Leprechaun.

**Assumed Order**

Several actions happen here, what order should those actions happen? My assumption is that they happen in this order:

1. Play extra minion
2. Resolve the ability of the extra minion
3. Move the Leprechaun to another base
4. Destroy the minion if it is less power than the Leprechaun.

Is this correct? If not, what should it be? I wasn't able to find in the rules that addresses all these types of actions.

**Why does this matter?**

If the Leprechaun should destroy the minion before it's moved, it may have a different level of power before it's moved. For example, if the Leprechaun is moved to a base with the Sleep Spores action played on it, it has -1 power. This could affect whether or not the extra minion is lower power than it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct order is:

1. Commission is played. This triggers two abilities in order. (Step 2 and 4)
2. An extra minion is placed on the base. This triggers the ongoing ability of the Leprechaun. (Step 3)
3. The new minion has less power so it will be destroyed. But it's ability is resolved first. If any. At the end of this step, the minion is gone.
4. The next ability ability of Commission is now executed. And Leprechaun is moved to another base.

The rules of Smash-up are vague and conflicting (even the rules admit this). So you need common sense to resolve this. But in this case it is clear that both actions of Commission are executed in order (Play an extra minion. **Then** move another player's minion from the extra minion's base to another base.)

Comment: I agree with this. However, if the minion was, for example, a Bear Cavalry, and chased the Leprechaun away, I think that the Leprechaun wouldn't trigger. This is because the Leprechaun triggers **after** a minion is played **here**, but after the minion is played it's no longer here.

Comment: Yup the rules are intentionally vague. Gives sometimes interesting discussions during game play ;-)